# C++ Instantiate an object into an STL container

Tags: c++, oop

I would like to automatically add an object into an STL vector container, whenever its constructor is called.

```
class TestClass
{
    public:
        TestClass();
}

TestClass::TestClass()
{
    aSTLVectorContainer.push_back("this object");
}
```

This obviously assumes that I have already instantiated the vector container aSTLVectorContainer.

Could someone let me know how to do this properly, and whether it is possible?

Comment: Do you want the class to automatically add itself to a vector?

Comment: Please make up a better example

Comment: Do you want to make sure that vector is already instantiated?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the current istance with `this`

So your code should be:

```
aSTLVectorContainer.push_back(this);
```

Although I would **vote against** such solution. Of course in this case your container must be of type `TestClass*`

Comment: Thank you - that works ok. How can I access the first object in the vector of pointers to TestClass? I have tried to access the first object I created by:      aSTLVectorContainer[0] - but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This solution looks like a recipe for dangling pointers or a maintenance nightmare.